# equally spaced "histogram" in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a number vector, let's say v=[1 1 1 1000 20 20]; I want to build very simple histogram-like plot where y-axis will be counts ( 3,1,2 in this case), but the x-axis will be 1,20,1000 equally spaced. Meaning that Matlab will ignore the fact that 1000>>20 and space them as it will 1,2,3 in the plot.
I will show that I mean. I can do it by:

```
x=[1 1 1 1000 20 20];
histogram('Categories',{'1','20','1000'},'BinCounts',[numel(find(x==1)), numel(find(x==20)), numel(find(x==1000))])
```

But it's kind of clumsy and gawky way. I have to know the categories beforehand. Can it be done in more elegant way?

Comment: By "more elegant", do you mean you just want to remove the hard-coded categories and `find(x==*)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first convert X to categorical matrix
[convert to categorical](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2020a/matlab/ref/categorical.html?searchHighlight=categorical&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)
then histogramplot X with these categories:
[plot categorial histogram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2020a/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html#buy5k3l)

in case of your problem:

```
C = categorical(x,[1 20 1000],{'1','20','1000'})
//or just C=categorical(x,[1 20 1000]) or simply C=categorical(x)
histogram(C)
```

Comment: as simple as that?.. I didn't know "categorical" function, thanks.